# compare two fields in csv file

Tags: python

If I have

```
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
for line in csv_reader:
    if line['Title'] == ???:
```

and want to check if the field in each `line` (row) in column `Title` is the same as the field right after it in the next `line`.
For extra clarification: if you consider row to be x and column to be y: I want to check if (row, column) == (row + 1, column) where column is called `Title`.
How can I achieve this? I tried doing
if line['Title'] == next(line)['Title']:
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

there is many ways to achieve it, but one of them is this

```py
csv_reader = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file))
for i in range(len(csv_reader)-1):
    if csv_reader[i]['Title'] == csv_reader[i+1]['Title']:
```

Comment: This returns an error saying that `TypeError: object of type 'DictReader' has no len()` I used `len(list(csv_reader))-1`, but it gives me this error `TypeError: 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: sorry was missing a `list()` call to convert to list, updated the answer